# Promise is never evaluated in Svelte API endpoint

Tags: javascript, async-await, svelte, sveltekit

I have written an API endpoint with the following code in Svelte that should help with getting a number of objects from a Prisma.io ORM based database.

The API endpoint is located at `routes/api/[slug].json.ts` and contains a get function:

```html
export async function get({ params }) {
    const { slug } = params
    const objects = await prisma[slug].findMany({})
    objects.forEach(function (object, index: number) {
        object.objectId = index
    })
    
    return objects
}
```

My view functionality is located in a Svelte file, called `Cardview.svelte`. It contains the following code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let object_model: string;
  let title = toTitleCase(object_model);

  async function obtain_objects(object_model: string) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/' + object_model + '.json';
    const objects = await fetch(url);
    return objects;
  }
  let objects = obtain_objects('measurement');
</script>

{#await objects}
  Reading from server... <Spinner size="sm" type="grow" />
{:then objects}
  <Container>
    {#each objects as v}
      <div class="shadow mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <Varcard variable={v} />
      </div>
    {/each}
  </Container>
{:catch error}
  There was an error in loading the JSON {object_model}.
  <div><span>{error.message}</span></div>
{/await}
```

Some layout imports from other files were omitted.

The problem with this code is that the `let objects = ..` part is never evaluated by the `{#await...` syntax. This means, the page is always stuck in loading phase and the Javascript-object `objects` always stays inside a promise. Where is the problem in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get function is not returning correctly. You need to return your data in the 'body' attribute of your return:

```js
return {
body: objects
}
```

Using fetch also requires an extra step:

```js
async function obtain_objects(object_model: string) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/' + object_model + '.json';
    const objects = await fetch(url);
    return objects.json();
  }
```

There are examples of the fetch api here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: You also have to `await` the last part: `return await objects.json()`

Comment: the Svelte {#await} should take care of that. Maybe not.